# SQL - Matching two rows from multiple columns in one table to 1 row in another table.

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a way in postgres to match two columns from one of my tables to a single column in another table, without getting rid of the first tables columns. I may not explain this so well so here's an example

```
Table 1:                        Table 2:
col1    col2    col3            2col1   2col2 
1       A       B               A       13.1  
2       A       C               B       18.3
3       B       C               C       21.7
4       B       D               D       11.23
```

I want to get back a table where col2 and col3 can both match to what's in 2col1, and replace their values with what's in 2col2.

So the result would be:

```
Table 1: 
col1   col2   col3
1      13.1   18.3
2      13.1   21.7
3      18.3   21.7
4      18.3   11.23
```

Comment: Join Table 2 twice once on col2 and once on col3; and remove mysql and sql-server tags if you are looking for a postgresql solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.2col2 AS col2, t3.2col2 AS col3
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.2col1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON t1.col3 = t2.2col1
```

Answer (score 1):

This can help you. LEFT JOIN is your friend

```
SELECT
  t1.col1,
  t2.2col2,
  t3.2col2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.col2 = t2.2col1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON t1.col3 = t3.2col1;
```